# CCLで、LANで繋いだ他のPCから、ファイルをloadしたい

Tags: common-lisp

無線LANで2つのPC、`Note-PC`と`Desk-PC`を繋いでいます。Desk-PCに、directory、D:/Data/Lisp/の下にFile1.clという名のCommon Lispのファイルを作成してあります。Note-PCでClozure CLを立ち上げ、Desk-PCのファイル、File1.clを`(load "//Desk-PC/Data/Lisp/File1.cl")`を評価しloadしようと試みましたが、`File "//Desk-PC/Data/Lisp/File1.cl" does not exist.`のエラーが出てうまく行きません。
因みに、Allegro、CLISP、SBCLではちゃんとloadされます。勿論、Desk-PCで立ち上げたCCLからは、`(load "D:/Data/Lisp/File1.cl")`でload出来ます。
CCLで他のPCのファイルにアクセスするにはどうしたらよいか、何方かお教えください。

Comment: Note-PCからDesk-PCに対して、エクスプローラ等から共有ファイルへのアクセス自体は問題ないのでしょうか？

Comment: cubickさんへ：Note-PCからDesk-PCに対して、エクスプローラ等から共有ファイルへのアクセス自体は問題ないのでしょうか？>>問題ありません

Answer (score 0):

詳しいことは調べきれなかったのですが、Windows版のCCLはネットワーク共有のパスを認識してくれないようです。  
共有場所にドライブレター(Z:等)を付与すればアクセスできるようですが、こちらの方法が手軽ではないでしょうか(他の処理系と記述を分けないといけないのが面倒ですが)

切り分けは、`#+ccl 式`を利用すれば簡単に可能ではあります。  
`#+ccl`でCCLのとき有効、`#-ccl`はCCLのとき無効

```
(load #-ccl "D:/Data/Lisp/File1.cl" #+ccl "X:/Data/Lisp/File1.cl")
```